# How to create maven project to support Intelllij project structure?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ community version and I am trying to create jersey project,but my intelliJ is not allowing this feature.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mkyong.rest -DartifactId=RESTfulExample 
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

But as here, I created maven project from command prompt and I saw ,I needed to add extra support for the IDE.Since this command as given down in figure is for Eclipse,What is the command should I run for IntelliJ to change it so that IntelliJ will support it?

[image]

Comment: Try searching the web for [`intellij maven`](https://www.google.com/search?q=intellij+maven), and you'll find lots of articles about how to use IntelliJ with Maven projects.

Comment: What's the specific issue when you open the project from `pom.xml`?

Comment: When you open the generated project with your IDE (IntelliJ or Eclipse), it will configure the project automatically and add needed files.